# Books on Group Theory between 1885-1900

Tags: reference-request, group-theory

While reading the book of Burnside, the history gave interest to me to see further the old books on group theory.

It will be a great pleasure if one can suggest some books on group theory published between 1885 to 1900.

I will not worry for the languages of the books (German, English, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The he earliest one seems to be
C. Jordan, Traite des substitutions algebriques:

C. Jordan,  Traite des substitutions et des equations algebriques. (French)
Paris. Gauthier-Villars. 1870. Published: 1870

The most comprehensive one covering this period is
Dickson, Linear groups with an exposition of the Galois field theory. (German)
Leipzig: B. G. Teubner. X + 312 S. (Teubners Sammlung No. VI.) Published: 1901

If you are also interested in papers, read C. Jordan, for example,
Memoire sur les groupes des mouvements.
Brioschi Ann. (2). II. 168-215. 320-345. Published: 1868

and Oeuvres Complete of Lie and Killing, Also Cartan:

Cartan, E.
Sur la structure des groupes de transformations finis et continus. (French)
These presentee a la Faculte des Sciences. 156 S. Paris. Nony et Co. Published: 1894,

Sur la reduction a sa forme canonique de la structure d'un groupe de transformations fini et continu. (French)
American J. 18, 1-61. Published: 1896

Beside this, papers of
Arthur Cayley, Sylov, Holder, Mattheu, Klein, Burnside and Frobenius.

To find their papers use Jahrbuch database,
http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/jfmen/MATH/JFM/full.html
which is available free on Internet, unlike Mathscinet and Zentralblatt, and covers the late 19s century very well.

Answer (score 0):

Several sources include this:
https://www.math.lsu.edu/~adkins/m7200/GroupHistory.pdf (Which specifies certain lectures and resources)

And this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_mathematics#Abstract_algebra

Pardon my French, but it appears most resources in that time were written in it.

Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/historical-textbook-on-group-theory-algebra) question.

Comment: I would like to see the references; books; anything. I am not worrying about the language of the books.